# laser scan to occupancy grid using costmap_2d [new user]

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d-ros, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Acording to http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d it takes in sensor data from the world and builds a 2D occupancy grid of the data. I have a published topic: /scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) and I want to use costmap_2d to provide a current occupancy grid. (sensor data --> [2d costmap] --> 2d occupancy grid)

But the same reference (http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) says:

- Subscribed Topics:

1. /footprint (geometry_msgs/Polygon)

- Published Topics:

1. /grid (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)
2. /grid_updates (nav_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate)
3. /voxel_grid (costmap_2d/VoxelGrid)

It seems the costmap_2d doesn't subscribe the (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) that I have it published. The only subscribed topic for costmap_2d is: /footprint (geometry_msgs/Polygon). What should I do to have /scan topic subscribed to costmap_2d node? (I'm trying to use standalone costmap_2d node)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191283/laser-scan-to-occupancy-grid-using-costmap_2d-%5Bnew-user%5D/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<s>You can't run costmap_2d as a node, however you can write your own node that will contain a Costmap2DROS object and little else.</s>  As David points out below, you CAN run a costmap_2d node that does this for you.

Check out the [API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html), as well as how the object is typically used in [move_base](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L111).

Costmaps don't explicitly subscribe to any sensors, they delegate that to layers. Setting up an obstacle layer to subscribe to a laser sensor source is done using parameters, and is described here - http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks Paul. It seems more complicated than I thought. I will proceed with the steps and share the result here.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-26**:
You are incorrect on the first point, Paul. You can run it as its own node. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_node.cpp

The rest is correct.